# Is this some kind of referencing problem? Value not sticking

Tags: vb.net, class, structure, value-type

Apologies for the appalling title.

I have mocked up this code to mimic an issue I was encountering on a project.

I want to know why the property *status* does not 'stick'. Stepping through the code I can even see it setting the property!

Is it something to do with Structure being a value type?

Here is the code, it is standalone.

```
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class clsTest
    Public Shared Sub test()
        Dim myHolder As New holder

        myHolder.info = New info(5)
        With myHolder.info
            Debug.Print("Initialised Status : {0}", .status)
            Debug.Print("Initialised Original Status : {0}", .originalStatus)
            myHolder.setStatusToTen()
            Debug.Print("Next Status : {0}", .status)
            Debug.Print("Next Original Status : {0}", .originalStatus)
        End With
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class holder
    Private _heldInfo As info

    Public Property info() As info
        Get
            Return _heldInfo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As info)
            _heldInfo = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub setStatusToTen()
        _heldInfo.status = 10
    End Sub
End Class

Public Structure info
    Private _iOriginalStatus, _iStatus As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal iStartingStatus As Integer)
        _iOriginalStatus = iStartingStatus
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property originalStatus() As Integer
        Get
            Return _iOriginalStatus
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property status() As Integer
        Get
            Return _iStatus
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _iStatus = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Structure
```

When I run `clsTest.test` I get the following output-

```
clsTest.test
Initialised Status : 0
Initialised Original Status : 5
Next Status : 0
Next Original Status : 5
```

...even though `setStatusToTen` is doing exactly what it says on the tin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its because Structures are value types. When a struct object is assigned to another struct object, the full content of the struct is copied and duplicated. ([See this C# example](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/04/c-structs/))

So in your code, this set:

```
Set(ByVal value As info)
        _heldInfo = value
End Set
```

... effectively results in two copies of the structure being made. One is internal to `holder` and is represented by `_heldInfo`, and the other is 'external' to `holder`, and is represented by `myHolder.info`. After the copy has been made, when you set values on one of them, the other is not affected.

If you add this method to `holder`:

```
Public Sub printStatus()
    Debug.Print("Internal Status : {0}", _heldInfo.status)
End Sub
```

... you will find where your value of `10` went.

Comment: Ok, I think I kind of understand! Thanks for the printStatus() method :)

Answer (score 2):

This is yet another case of mutable structs being evil. Avoid using structures for this purpose. As a reference:

[Why are mutable structs “evil”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)